# jQuery change() doesn't work for the first onclick event but works for the next successive clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button as following:

```
<li class="cnt-li">
  <button class="btn-container" title="Add Container" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".add-ctn-modal">
    <img src="images/add.png" alt="Add Container">
  </button>
</li>
```

I have a long modal div as following:

```
<div class="modal fade add-ctn-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Container</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ctn-num" class="control-label">Container Number:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ctn-num">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="add_btn_modal" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So when I click on the button, the above modal opens up, which has an input box and an add button. When I enter some number like say "5" and click on add, the text in the div mentioned below needs to be changed to the entered value which is 5 in this case.[By default, the value is 0]. But it doesn't change.

This is the div:

```
<div>
  <label id="ctn-info-label">Container Number : <span class="container-no">0</span></label>
</div>
```

I wrote the following script to achieve this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add_btn_modal').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $('#ctn-num').change(function(){
        $('.container-no').text($(this).val());
      })
  });
});
```

This script is working but from the second click onwards. 
First time: I enter the number and click on Add. It doesn't change.
Second time: I change the value and click on Add. The value changes and for further clicks. 
Once I reload the page and try it again, it won't work for the first time.

Am I missing something here in the script? Could anyone help me with this.

Comment: @j08691 : Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: you're missing a seml colon from after the last .val());})    just thought i'd point it out

Comment: Yeah I just saw it. I was about to make an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#add_btn_modal').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault(); 
      $('.container-no').text($('#ctn-num').val());
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s129mm2L/

Comment: Thanks a lot :)  Works perfect. TomSlick's answer was very useful too.

Answer (score 3):

You're setting a change handler within another change handler. The inner handler will only fire once it is set (after the first click).

Answer (score 0):

Change it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ctn-num').on("change", function(){
       $('.container-no').text($(this).val());
    });
 });
```

Also, I'm not sure why you are using classes to set the text of a label when it only appears once.  Looks like you should be using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#ctn-num').on("change", function(){
       $('#ctn-info-label').text($(this).val());
    });
 });
```